# Issues with uploading images Drupal 6

Tags: theming, 6

I am helping a client get back up to speed with their website on a strict budget.

So key is keep the site updated for Drupal 6 through the year then upgrade to latest stable version of Drupal first of next year.

Having said this, I am not as familiar with Drupal 6 and keep getting a warning message when using rich-text icon to upload an image into the body field of a node.

Here is the message:

Properties: Change how the image is displayed.

ImageField Assist Upload "name of image.jpg or .png" has been created.

```
warning: Parameter 2 to imagefield_assist_properties_form() expected to be a reference, value given in /mnt/stor2-wc2-dfw1/428972/572960/www.kennebecriverangler.com/web/content/includes/form.inc on line 378.
```

on line 378 of form.inc is this code:

```
  $form = call_user_func_array(isset($callback) ? $callback : $form_id, $args);
```

Also if this info helps, the theme has been adapted from a WordPress theme...
and configured with CCK, imagefield assist imagefield import and imagefieldAPI.

Comment: What version of [ImageField](https://drupal.org/project/imagefield)?

Comment: Also, from `ImageField Assist Upload "name of image.jpg or .png" has been created.`, are you sure you aren't leaving the name field blank??

Comment: The name field is not blank - name of image appears (just used "name-of-image.jpg" or "name-of-image.png" as an example.

Comment: Right, website hasn't had attention lately - the imageField assist version: imagefield-6.x-3.1. Is it worth it to upgrade all these image modules, and cck to latest version of 6? or take it to 7, if the client has it in the budget? Advice much appreciated.

Comment: The issue here is, we can troubleshoot this item in 6, or you can upgrade to at least 7 Core as all the Image Items have been migrated.  Can you build a subdomain on your customer's site

Comment: I agree - troubleshooting in 6 doesn't make sense, does it. I believe time to help client get to 7. Then see how 8 works out, maybe still appropriate for small businesses?

Comment: if you need any help, look me up... If you need to borrow some web space let me know too

Comment: not a problem :)